# How to navigate to a specific screen without passing through transition screens. React-Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation for handling my app navigation. And I have a use case where I receive a Screen name by initialProps at the initialize of the application, and with that string, I need to navigate to such screen without passing from the intermediate screens.

Example:

- TabNavigator1

  - StackNavigatorA

    - ScreenA
    - ScreenB
- TabNavigator2

InitialProps: { navigateTo: /TabNavigator1/StackNavigatorA/ScreenA }

This should redirect directly (like a deep link) to the ScreenA.
Does anyone know how I can do this? O some approach I should consider? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add duplicate route, such as:

- TabNavigator1

  - StackNavigatorA

    - ScreenA (link to one screen component)
    - ScreenB
- TabNavigator2
- ScreenA (link to one screen component)

if there is a connection between A and B, can ScreenB take out too